# GRUB Customizer: EFI/ubuntu/fonts/unicode.pf2 not found

Tags: boot, grub2

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and I dual-boot Pop!_OS with it. And I used `grub2` for GRUB Customizer.

Now I am not able boot into Ubuntu, but I am able to boot into Pop!_OS. Whenever I am trying to boot into Ubuntu, it is showing:

> EFI/ubuntu/fonts/unicode.pf2 not found.

Please help me. How should I resolve this error?

Comment: Grub Customizer replaces grub with its own proxy files. Better to totally reinstall grub2. Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair You can use Advanced options & choose the total reinstall. But do not know how it may see Pop!OS.